# case_when() function with select()

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to select some columns with `case_when()` function

```r
df %>%
   {
      case_when(
         .$ID == 1 ~ select(., Level, Time),
         .$ID == 2 ~ select(., Time, Upgrade),
         TRUE ~ select(., Level, Time, Upgrade)
      )
   }
```

But, if I use `if()` statement - it works:

```r
df %>%
   {
      if(.$ID == 1) {
      select(., Level, Time)
      } else if(.$ID == 2) {
      select(., Time, Upgrade)
      } else {
      select(., Level, Time, Upgrade)
      }
   }
```

I got error that `select()` after `TRUE ~` statement must have number of columns equal to number of columns of `select()` after `.$ID == 1`.

How I could use `case_when()` function in this case?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what `case_when` does and what it returns. Also note that assuming there's more than 1 row in `df`, you'll get a warning with `if(df$ID == 1)` because it will only check the first value in that vector. With a sample of data, folks might be able to help more specifically

Comment: ... on @camille's comment, (1) add `group_by(ID) %>%` before the `{...}` block; (2) change all references of `.$ID` to `.$ID[1]`; then (3) add `%>% ungroup()` after the `{...}` block.